# No activity found to handle intent{act=android,intent.action.VIEW}

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an image located at path **temp_path** .i want that image to be opened with Android gallery app .To do so i add following code inside a function in **Fragment**

```
File file=new File(temp_path);
Uri uri;
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<24)
{
   uri=Uri.fromFile(file);
}
else
  {
     uri=Uri.parse(file.getPath());
  }
  Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  intent.setDataAndType(uri,"jpg/jpeg/png");
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  startActivity(intent);
```

But i am getting following exception

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.force/files/Pictures/temp_image.jpg typ=jpg/jpeg/png flg=0x10000000 }
```

How to resolve this exception.

**Tried Solution 1(adding fileprovider)**
I added provider into AndroidManifest.xml

```
<provider
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_path"/>
</provider>
```

Also created provider_path.xml as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="."/>
</paths>
```

and also modified my java code to

```
    File file=new File(temp_path);
    Uri uri;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    {
        uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext() ,getContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
    } else
    {
        uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    }
    Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri,"jpg/jpeg/png");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

But still getting the same Exception

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.example.force.provider/external_files/Android/data/com.example.force/files/Pictures/temp_image.jpg typ=jpg/jpeg/png flg=0x10000000 }
```

**note value of dat** :is it right?

my image is located at path `/Android/data/com.example.force/files/Pictures/temp_image.jpg` in external storage

**Tried Solution 2:**
I added provider into AndroidManifest.xml

```
<provider
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_path"/>
</provider>
```

Also created provider_path.xml

**Modified** as compared to  tried solution 1

```
<paths
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="com.example.force"
        path="."/>
</paths>
```

and also modified my java code to as compared to tried solution 1

```
    File file=new File(temp_path);
    Uri uri;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    {
        uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext() ,getContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
    } else
    {
        uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    }
String mime="/*";
                    MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap=MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
                    if(mimeTypeMap.hasExtension(mimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(uri.toString())))
                    {
                        mime=mimeTypeMap.getMimeTypeFromExtension(mimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(uri.toString()));
                }

    Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri,mime);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

this time no exception arise but gallery app is displaying File format isn't supported  or files are corrupted and if i see detail of image its  picking path of image as

```
`content://com.example.force.provider/com.example.force./Android/data/com.example.force/files/Pictures/temp_image.jpg`
```

but right path of image file is

```
/Android/data/com.example.force/files/Pictures/temp_image.jpg
```

Comment: You should be crashing with a `FileUriExposedException`. Please use `FileProvider` and its `getUriForFile()` for obtaining the `Uri` to use. Also, please use a valid MIME type. It is *your* content, so *you* are responsible for stating what the MIME type is of that content.

Comment: @CommonsWare i tried using file provider check in Tried Solution 1 and exception it throws

Comment: Did you fix the MIME type? `jpg/jpeg/png` is not a valid MIME type, and there will be approximately zero apps on the planet that support it.

Comment: @CommonsWare check tried solution 2

Comment: "but right path of image file is" -- you are sending a `Uri`, not a path. Add `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to your `Intent` as a flag.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you finally image is correctly displayed in gallery

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Intellij Amiya and  CommonsWare for helping .
Final solution to this problem is achieved by adding tried solution 2 and also adding flag to intent

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```